# Is it possible on FFMPEG to send RTSP raw frames to pipe and write video segments by time to the disk?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to receive RTSP frames to be processed by OpenCV, via ffmpeg using python. This is ok.
However I also need to write this video to disk one video each minute. This last part is the problem.

This is ok and works, but only write to a single file 'OUTPUT.TS':

```
command = ['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
           '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',   # Force TCP (for testing)
           '-max_delay', '30000000',   # 30 seconds (sometimes needed because the stream is from the web).
           '-i', STREAM_ADDRESS,
           '-f', 'rawvideo',           # Video format is raw video
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',        # bgr24 pixel format matches OpenCV default pixels format.
           '-an', 'pipe:',
           '-vcodec', 'copy', '-y', 'OUTPUT.TS']

ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but since I'm using -f RAW I can't add something like

```
'-f segment -segment_time 1800 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts'
```

I tried to use some ffmpeg combinations but without success, since I cant gave two -f  flags.

There are any way to do this on FFMPEG without start/stop the ffmpeg process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are two outputs, it is possible to use `-f rawvideo` for the first output and `-f segment` to the second output.

Since RTSP and PIPE makes it more difficult to reproduce, we may use an MP4 video file as input, and `tmp.bgr` file as raw output (for testing):

Example:
`ffmpeg.exe -y -an -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 tmp.bgr -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts"`

The above example is working - the output is a large raw video file named `tmp.bgr` and multiple segment files named `2023-04-02_23-04-12.ts`, `2023-04-02_23-04-13.ts`, `2023-04-02_23-04-14.ts`...

---

I am not going to test is with Python, but it supposed to be as follows:

```python
command = ['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
           '-y', '-an',                # Ignore audio stream of the input
           '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',   # Force TCP (for testing)
           '-max_delay', '30000000',   # 30 seconds (sometimes needed because the stream is from the web).
           '-i', STREAM_ADDRESS,
           '-f', 'rawvideo',           # Video format is raw video
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',        # bgr24 pixel format matches OpenCV default pixels format.
           'pipe:',                    # First output goes to PIPE.
           '-vcodec', 'copy',          # -vcodec copy applies the second output.
           '-f', 'segment', '-segment_time', '60', '-strftime', '1', '"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts"']  # Second output to segmented TS files.
```